# Get ordered index by dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have something like the following dataframe indexed by state and year:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame(index=['CA', 'WA', 'OR', 'NV'])
d[2015]=[100, 200, 40, 75]
d[2016]=[1000, 20, 25, 12]
print d
    2015  2016
CA   100  1000
WA   200    20
OR    40    25
NV    75    12
```

I want a new dataframe where the index is the rank of each state for that year, and the values are the states in their ranked order.

I can get that output as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame([d.sort_values(x).index for x in d.columns], index=d.columns, columns=range(1,len(d)+1)).transpose()
Out[57]: 
  2015 2016
1   OR   NV
2   NV   WA
3   CA   OR
4   WA   CA
```

Is there a cleaner way of getting this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `argsort`, which returns the index to sort each column, apply it to the index gives the ranked index in ascending order:

```
d.apply(lambda x: x.index[x.argsort()])
```

[image]

you can call `reset_index(drop=True)` if you don't want to keep the original index on the data frame.

Comment: and now to complicate things (sorry I didn't initially think of this exception). Say I have a missing value in my initial dataframe - it will show up as the last sorted item in the output when I think it should instead show up as null. I can get my desired answer using a variation of my initial clunky method, but cannot figure out how to do it within your framework.

Comment: Use `np.where` to replace the index with null when the value is null, and also use `np.argsort` instead of pandas.Series.argsort here will be better: `d.apply(lambda x: x.index.where(x.notnull(), np.nan)[x.values.argsort()])`

Answer (score 2):

with an obnoxious amount of formatting

```
d.apply(pd.Series.rank).stack().reset_index(0, name='x') \
    .set_index('x', append=True).squeeze() \
    .unstack(0).rename_axis(None).rename(index=int)

  2015 2016
1   OR   NV
2   NV   WA
3   CA   OR
4   WA   CA
```

Or better with `numpy`

```
a = d.values.argsort(0)

pd.DataFrame(d.index.values[a], range(1, len(d) + 1), d.columns)

  2015 2016
1   OR   NV
2   NV   WA
3   CA   OR
4   WA   CA
```